# SQL Query to split data based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have the following data:

```
SR_ID   OPEN_DATE   OPEN_WEEK   PRIORITY    TTRespond
------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------
24720   01/10/2014  40          P2 - High   3.867066667
24437   11/09/2014  37          P2 - High   418.1992333
24007   04/08/2014  32          P1 - Urgent 12571.28308
24628   25/09/2014  39          P2 - High   3.0407
24446   12/09/2014  37          P2 - High   2694.122933
24420   10/09/2014  37          P3 - Normal 
24479   15/09/2014  38          P2 - High   90.56748333
24924   15/10/2014  42          P3 - Normal 26.51546667
24706   01/10/2014  40          P2 - High
```

I am trying to write a query that will return the data in the last column (TTRespond) in separate columns based on the value in OPEN_WEEK and PRIORITY.

I would like to return the data like this:

```
Priority    P1 - Urgent P1 - Urgent P1 - Urgent P1 - Urgent P1 - Urgent P1 - Urgent
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Week #      31          32          33          34          35          36
```

I do not want to summarise the data (i.e. Count  Average etc), I simply want to return all rows that match the two criteria. I achieved the result using an array based formula in Excel, but it is very slow and cannot cope with the source record set (only 25,000 rows).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It seems like you have a great question brewing there... however, I think you need to add a bit more detail on what exactly the expected behavior is (what does "Urgent Week # 31 32 33 34 35 36" mean??). Like maybe create the desired output in a similar form to your starting data?

Comment: You mention `return the data in the last column (TTRespond)` but in the data you want to return you have not mentioned `TTRespond`. Is there any reason you are not displaying that? Can you please explain this?

Comment: However I'm reading your question I cannot understand what it is that you want. On one hand it sound like you just want a WHERE-clause like "WHERE OPEN_WEEK = @openWeekParam AND PRIORITY = @priorityParam" and on the other hand it sound like you just want something like "GROUP BY OPEN_WEEK, PRIORITY". So please explain a little more what you want. You mention you want TTRespons but in your reponse-example TTRespons isn't there.

Comment: You have some missing values for the `TTRespond` column, what are the default values for these?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  But supposing you're looking for an output something like this, where the priority/week number are columns, and all the possible matching values are listed out in rows:

```
P2 - High, Week 37 | P2 - High, Week 38 | P2 - High, Week 39 | P2 - High, Week 40
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
418.1992333        | 90.56748333        | 3.0407             | 3.867066667
2694.122933        |                    |                    |
```

This kind of "row/column inversion" is called a pivot table.  Simple pivot tables can be done with clever usage of `group by` and `max` clauses in the following fashion in SQL Server:

```
;with T as (
    select
        row_number() over (partition by priority, open_week order by open_date) ix
        ,T.*
    from MyTable T
    where TTrespond is not null
), R as (
    select distinct ix from T
)
select
    R.ix
    ,max(case when [OPEN_WEEK]=37 and T.ix=R.ix and [PRIORITY]='P2 - High' then TTRespond end) as [P2 - High, Week 37]
    ,max(case when [OPEN_WEEK]=38 and T.ix=R.ix and [PRIORITY]='P2 - High' then TTRespond end) as [P2 - High, Week 38]
    ,max(case when [OPEN_WEEK]=39 and T.ix=R.ix and [PRIORITY]='P2 - High' then TTRespond end) as [P2 - High, Week 39]
    ,max(case when [OPEN_WEEK]=40 and T.ix=R.ix and [PRIORITY]='P2 - High' then TTRespond end) as [P2 - High, Week 40]
from T, R
group by R.ix
```

The possible values can be expanded by adding more column combinations modeled after the examples above.